# Moving large files in java

Tags: java, file

I have to move files from one directory to other directory.

Am using property file. So the source and destination path is stored in property file.
Am haivng property reader class also.

In my source directory am having lots of files. One file should move to other directory if its complete the operation.

File size is more than 500MB.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;


public class Main1 
{

    public static String primarydir="";
    public static String secondarydir="";

    public static void main(String[] argv) 
    throws Exception
    {

        primarydir=PropertyReader.getProperty("primarydir");
        System.out.println(primarydir);

        secondarydir=PropertyReader.getProperty("secondarydir");

        File dir = new File(primarydir);

        secondarydir=PropertyReader.getProperty("secondarydir");


        String[] children = dir.list();
        if (children == null)
        {
            System.out.println("does not exist or is not a directory");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) 
            {
                String filename = children[i];
                System.out.println(filename);

                try
                {
                    File oldFile = new File(primarydir,children[i]);  

                    System.out.println( "Before Moving"+oldFile.getName());

                    if (oldFile.renameTo(new File(secondarydir+oldFile.getName()))) 
                    {  
                        System.out.println("The file was moved successfully to the new folder");  
                    }
                    else 
                    {  
                        System.out.println("The File was not moved.");  
                    }  
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {  
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }  
            }
            System.out.println("ok");
        }
    }

}
```

My code is not moving the file into the correct path.

This is my property file

```
primarydir=C:/Desktop/A
secondarydir=D:/B
enter code here
```

Files should be in B drive. How to do? Any one can help me..!!

Comment: `FileChannel.transferTo()` might be what you need.

Comment: I think your directories should end with `"\"`. This way `dir + file.getName()` would yield a valid path.

Comment: In the code you provided make sure secondarydir is ending with a '\'.
No need for that in case of primarydir.

Comment: `File.rename()` won't work when source / target path are on different partition on linux, so it probably won't work on windows too, you need check the `boolean` return value to know whether it succeed or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
oldFile.renameTo(new File(secondarydir+oldFile.getName()))
```

To this:

```
oldFile.renameTo(new File(secondarydir, oldFile.getName()))
```

It's best not to use string concatenation to join path segments, as the proper way to do it may be platform-dependent.

*Edit:* If you can use JDK 1.7 APIs, you can use `Files.move()` instead of `File.renameTo()`

Answer (score 0):

Code - a java method:

```
/**
 * copy by transfer, use this for cross partition copy,
 * @param sFile source file,
 * @param tFile target file,
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void copyByTransfer(File sFile, File tFile) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fInput = new FileInputStream(sFile);
    FileOutputStream fOutput = new FileOutputStream(tFile);
    FileChannel fReadChannel = fInput.getChannel();
    FileChannel fWriteChannel = fOutput.getChannel();

    fReadChannel.transferTo(0, fReadChannel.size(), fWriteChannel);

    fReadChannel.close();
    fWriteChannel.close();
    fInput.close();
    fOutput.close();
}
```

The method use nio, it make use os underling operation to improve performance.

---

Here is the import code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
```

If you are in eclipse, just use `ctrl + shift + o`.

Comment: You *may* want to include `import` statements.